# flying into EWR for flight to rome on Norwegian . coming from ATL on different airlines

Tags: ewr

Is there an estimate of how long it will take with the current Govt Shutdown, to get off the plane in EWR Delta (arrives at 8:05 pm), get luggage and re enter to check in for the Norwegian Air flight to Rome at 11:15 pm .

Comment: Two differnet tickets ?

Comment: @choster The question's title indicates arrival from ATL (Atlanta, Georgia, USA), so domestic.  TSA is the major government factor here, along with ground operations, which are not operated by the government.  Immigration-related departure controls are automated so they should not be at all delayed by the shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

If your flight actually arrives at 8:05 pm, you should be fine. You only interact with TSA, AFTER you have checked in and dropped your bags with Norwegian. If it takes you an hour to get off the plan and to collect your bags, you will still be at the Norwegian counter 2 hours before departure, which is well within their cutoff times (check in 1 hour , boarding 20 minutes). Both airlines operate from Terminal B, which helps.

However, no connection is ever guaranteed.  Your inbound may be delayed, your bags may lost, you might get rerouted because of weather, etc. On a single ticket the airline will take care of you and get you to your destination at no extra cost to you. On two separate tickets you carry the full risk yourself including having to buy a new same-day ticket, which can be expensive

While the risk of you missing this is small, it's not zero either and the impact is big if you miss it. My personal minimum two-ticket connection time is 4 hours, but everyone's risk tolerance is different